# closing my video call causes all active video connections closing

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm working on a webRTC project. I can connect with other clients in the room and hang up my video connection as well. The problem is that when I hang up my video call, all other video connections are disconnected. Please take a look at my code and let me how to change the code to disconnect *only* my video connection.

```js
/* Close the RTCPeerConnection and reset variables so that the user can 
make or receive another call if they wish. This is called both
when the user hangs up, the other user hangs up, or if a connection
failure is detected. */

function closeVideoCall() {
  var localVideo = document.getElementById("local_video");
  log("Closing the call");

  // Close the RTCPeerConnection
  if (myPeerConnection) {
    log("--> Closing the peer connection");

    // Disconnect all our event listeners; we don't want stray events
    // to interfere with the hangup while it's ongoing.
    myPeerConnection.ontrack = null;
    myPeerConnection.onnicecandidate = null;
    myPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = null;
    myPeerConnection.onnotificationneeded = null;

    // Stop all transceivers on the connection
    myPeerConnection.getTransceivers().forEach(transceiver => {
      transceiver.stop();
    });

    /* Stop the webcam preview as well by pausing the <video>
    element, then stopping each of the getUserMedia() tracks
    on it. */

    if (localVideo.srcObject) {
        localVideo.pause();
        localVideo.srcObject.getTracks ().forEach (track => {
            track.stop();
        });
    }

    // Close the peer connection
    myPeerConnection.close();
    myPeerConnection = null;
    webcamStream = null;
  }

  // Disable the hangup button
  document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = true;
  targetUsername = null;
}

/* Handle the "hang-up" message, which is sent if the other peer
has hung up the call or otherwise disconnected. */

function handleHangUpMsg(msg) {
  log("*** Received hang up notification from other peer");
  closeVideoCall();
}

/* Hang up the call by closing our end of the connection, then
sending a "hang-up" message to the other peer (keep in mind that
the signaling is done on a different connection). This notifies
the other peer that the connection should be terminated and the UI
returned to the "no call in progress" state. */

function hangUpCall() {
  closeVideoCall();
  sendToServer({
    name: myUsername,
    target: targetUsername,
    type: "hang-up"
  });
}
```

I want to close my active video call, but all active video connections were disconnected.

Comment: Probably the issue is in `closeVideoCall()` call? Is it closing the call for other users?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know which section of the code cause this issue?!